# Typo3 extension which requires some database columns to be uppercase

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I am a semi-experienced developer, however am fairly new to typo3. I have been tasked with updating a plugin from the old pi-based extension to extbase.

I am working with typo3 v7.6.

Some of the fields in the database are uppercase and need to remain that way.

However, the new naming convention for columns does not seem to allow for this.

Simply adding the property (in uppercase) and getter/setter to the model does not seem to retrieve the value from the database. Dumping the entire model, the property I define is null, and I see no evidence of the value stored in the database anywhere in the model.

What would I need to do to get models to work with these fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a mapping. Check out the core for examples
https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/extbase/ext_typoscript_setup.txt

Comment: Awesome, I had dug in far enough to see these mappings in use but had no idea how to define them. Thanks.